# iOS 7 action bar look in flex mobile application

Tags: ios, flash, apache-flex, mobile, builder

How to get iOS 7 action bar look in flex mobile application, I want my action bar to be completely flat and semi transparent too, I have seen few posts; those talks about making action bar flat by custom skin but no one talks about transparency.... any help or point to right direction would be greatly appreciated....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is set the `alpha` property on your custom skin:

From Adobe's [help documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WSA95C9644-B650-4783-B5C0-D2C7F95A23E3.html):

I added a transparent fill to the button's background/border `<s:Rect>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- SparkSkinning/GlobalVariableAccessorExample.mxml -->
<s:Application 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark">

    <fx:Script>
        public var myLabelString:String = "Hello World";
    </fx:Script>

    <s:Button skinClass="mySkins.GlobalVariableAccessorSkin"/>

</s:Application>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- SparkSkinning\mySkins\GlobalVariableAccessorSkin.mxml -->
<s:Skin 
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    minWidth="21" minHeight="21">

    <fx:Metadata>
        [HostComponent("spark.components.Button")]
    </fx:Metadata> 

    <fx:Script>
        import mx.core.FlexGlobals;        

        [Bindable]
        private var localString:String = FlexGlobals.topLevelApplication.myLabelString;
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- Specify one state for each SkinState metadata in the host component's class -->
    <s:states>
        <s:State name="up"/>
        <s:State name="over"/>
        <s:State name="down"/>
        <s:State name="disabled"/>
    </s:states>

    <s:Rect 
        left="0" right="0" 
        top="0" bottom="0" 
        width="69" height="20" 
        radiusX="2" radiusY="2">
        <s:stroke>
            <s:SolidColorStroke color="0x000000" weight="1"/>
        </s:stroke>
        <!--
          This section added to demonstrate
        -->
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0x999999" alpha="0.5"/>
        </s:fill>
        <!--  ----------------------- -->
    </s:Rect>

    <s:Label id="labelDisplay" 
        text="{localString}"
        horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="1"
        left="10" right="10" top="2" bottom="2">
    </s:Label>
</s:Skin>
```